# Event Log File Browser

Tags: heroku, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

I am trying to find out which reports a specific user has exported (ReportExport), but it doesnt seem to be available for download on Salesforce. Please see image below.

- For info, we are using enterprise edition of salesforce.
- Event Log File Browser: https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/

[image]

EDIT: Event Monitoring Licence required

Comment: Think you need the add on event monitoring licence for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Monitoring Licence required